# How do I pass a inout from a UnsafeMutablePointer with Swift 1.2

Tags: ios, swift

I am stuck after trying multiple ways around this. Seeking help desperately.

Here is a basic test case in playground:

```
import JavaScriptCore

func NativeLoggingHook(context: JSContextRef, object: JSObjectRef,  thisObject: JSObjectRef, argumentCount: size_t, arguments: [JSValueRef],  inout exception: JSValueRef) -> JSValueRef {
    // Do something useful
    return JSValueMakeUndefined(context)
}

var JSObjectCallAsFunctionCallback: @objc_block (JSContextRef, JSObjectRef, JSObjectRef, size_t, UnsafePointer<JSValueRef>, UnsafeMutablePointer<JSValueRef>) -> JSValueRef = { context, object,  thisObject, argumentCount, arguments, exception -> JSValueRef in
    let buffer: [JSValueRef] = Array<JSValueRef>(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: arguments, count: argumentCount))
    return NativeLoggingHook(context, object,  thisObject, argumentCount, buffer, exception) // <- How do I pass the exception to my Swift function?
}
```

I assume that I need to convert the UnsafePointer to an UnsafeBufferPointer with Swift 1.2 but how do I pass an UnsafeMutablePointer to a function that takes an inout? I tried `&` and many other variations but so far no luck.

**UPDATE:**

Here is the solution I have adopted to deal with bridging a callback from Objective-C & Swift.

```
import JavaScriptCore

func NativeLoggingHook(context: JSContextRef, object: JSObjectRef,  thisObject: JSObjectRef, argumentCount: size_t, arguments: [JSValueRef], exception: UnsafePointer<JSValueRef>) -> JSValueRef {
    // Do something useful
    return JSValueMakeUndefined(context) }

let block: @objc_block (JSContextRef, JSObjectRef, JSObjectRef, size_t, UnsafePointer<JSValueRef>, UnsafeMutablePointer<JSValueRef>)
-> JSValueRef = { context, object,  thisObject, argumentCount, arguments, exception -> JSValueRef in
    let buffer: [JSValueRef] = Array<JSValueRef>(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: arguments, count: argumentCount))
    return NativeLoggingHook(context, object,  thisObject, argumentCount, buffer, &exception.memory) }

let imp : COpaquePointer =
    imp_implementationWithBlock(unsafeBitCast(block, AnyObject.self))

let callback : JSObjectCallAsFunctionCallback =
    unsafeBitCast(imp, JSObjectCallAsFunctionCallback.self)

func setNativeHook(hook: JSObjectCallAsFunctionCallback) -> Bool {
    // Do something useful
    return true }

println(setNativeHook(callback))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this will actually work for you, but i got it to compile by unwrapping the pointer wrapper and passing the result by reference:

```
import JavaScriptCore

func NativeLoggingHook(context: JSContextRef, object: JSObjectRef,  thisObject: JSObjectRef, argumentCount: size_t, arguments: [JSValueRef],  inout exception: JSValueRef) -> JSValueRef {
    // Do something useful
    return JSValueMakeUndefined(context)
}

var JSObjectCallAsFunctionCallback: @objc_block (JSContextRef, JSObjectRef, JSObjectRef, size_t, UnsafePointer<JSValueRef>, UnsafeMutablePointer<JSValueRef>) -> JSValueRef = {
    (context, object,  thisObject, argumentCount, arguments, exception) -> JSValueRef in

    let buffer: [JSValueRef] = Array<JSValueRef>(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: arguments, count: argumentCount))
    return NativeLoggingHook(context, object, thisObject, argumentCount, buffer, &exception.memory)
    // <- pass the underlying memory type by reference?
}
```

Comment: It is compiling. I have updated my OP to produce the CFunctionPointer out of the @objc_block. Swift has many rough edges in bridging with Objective-C.

Comment: Yuck!  Do you mean though that you got what you need?

Comment: yeah sorry man. just punch the checkbox on your answer. you rock! thanks for helping out.